# How to make changes in enviroment variables permanent?

Tags: environment-variables

I have a virtual machine and have a need to setup environment variables.

I have several options to do that like `/etc/environment` or `~/.bashrc`. First one is global and second one is local and has a dependency on the running terminal.

As my aim is to run script from multiple users by CI `/etc/environment` is my option is go further.

However I faced with the issue. After VM restart some global variables (ANDROID_HOME) are not available.

The values are:

```
ANDROID_HOME="/opt/bitnami/apps/android-sdk-linux"
JAVA_HOME="/opt/bitnami/java"
PATH="/opt/bitnami/java/bin:/opt/bitnami/java/lib:/opt/bitnami/java:/opt/bitnami/apps/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/bitnami/apps/android-sdk-linux/build-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

In that form command `android list avd` is not recognised, but `java -version` is recognised. At the same time the same variables added via `export` and `source` call provides access to the tools (which means paths are correct).

Do you know what else can cause the issue with access to that global variable?

Comment: Your .bashrc may be overriding those. Set up those variables in .bashrc , at the end of file with export keyword

Comment: bashrc will work only for current user and wouldn't work for another one. Please correct me if I am not right

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  You didn't specify if it's only for you or globally for all users.  Alternate solution would be /etc/profile, that should work for all.  But i see from your answer you had a different issue involved there

Answer (score 0):

My issue was in lack of permission to the folder to my tools folder